# Old question with outdated answer, but still relevan. Re-ask or re-open?

Tags: discussion

[How do I manage virtual network settings in VMWare Player?](https://superuser.com/q/691079/86828)

The answer is outdated*, but the question not (I have the same question for the current version of the software). Should it be re-asked as a new independent question? Or some how "reopen" it? (it is not closed, it just has no "attraction", since it has an accepted answer)

* *as will every answer on the site be eventually...*

PS: I took another look and saw that the answer is actually still relevant (mostly). I added some edits to cover newer versions. Hmm, I just see the edit was rejected. The reason given: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."
I don't get it. Newer versions of Player require one extra step in the already posted solution, so I added it into the solution. Why was this deemed as "intended to address the author"? It is clearly enhancing the solution given and has nothing to do with the author. Is there anything I can do? I believe you can see the change here: https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/534734

Comment: I seem to recall VMware player is EOL - is this for player or something else? Or are people still running the last available version?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) is still around, it just has, a slightly different name now.

Comment: When a question asked, when a specific version of an application was "current", I lean towards wanting a new question if the answers to that existing question no longer apply to the new "current" version. I say this because a new answer with significant detail and differs significantly from the existing answer will be difficult to write. Now in this specific example the question does not specifically indicate the version being used, so an acceptable edit to the existing question might be possible or a new answer pointing out the differences between the (old) version and the current versions.

Answer (score 7):

Questions don't die when they get an accepted answer. Edits and new answers still bump them to the front page. It's definitely not unheard of for excellent new answers to be added to old answered questions.

If you're willing to spend a bit of reputation, you can place a bounty on the question; there's a predefined reason about the answer(s) being out of date.

It can be acceptable to ask a similar question for a new version. The key is that you have to mention the existing question and how the circumstances differ (i.e. what changed in the program that requires a new question); otherwise your question is likely to be closed as a duplicate. Share exactly how/why the existing answer doesn't work anymore. Some might still vote to close - preferring the bounty option - but I personally wouldn't have a problem with a new question.

Comment: If its for vmware workstation player, the name/question seems distinctive enough to me. And damn, vmware has confusing names for stuff now

Answer (score 1):

Looks like VMware changed the name of player to 'workstation player' (and have workstation player pro too). It would be sufficient to post a new question, reference back to the old one and mention it does not work. The title would be distinct (for searchability) as would the referencing to the old question showing you are aware of it.

Comment: I disagree. The old question (and answer) matches the new version 99%. It would just add unnecessary clutter. (to clarify: on first glance I missed that the answer is good also for new versions)